# ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am trying to implement IdentityDBContext.

I have these models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

I separated the context for both Identity and the application DB Contexts:

For the Identity I have:

```
public class ApplicationIdentityDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationIdentityDbContext> options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

Then for the application, I have:

Then in the ApplicationDbContext, I have this:

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}
```

I customized the Identity keys from string to long.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<DDMDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I got this error in the ApplicationIdentityDbContext:

> Error CS0311  ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

How do I correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: [`ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.apiauthorization.identityserver.apiauthorizationdbcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) takes one generic type parameter: `TUser`. You're passing a whopping eight! It's not clear why you're trying to do this.

Comment: @canton7 - I re-write my code and separated the DBContext for both Identity and the ApplicationDb. But the error in the ApplicationIdentityDbContext changed to: ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your updated code and the new error

Comment: @canton7 - I have done that. Kindly see the new error:  ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>'

Comment: `TUser` has to extend `IdentityUser` (the generic type constraint is `where TUser : IdentityUser`). Your `ApplicationUser` extends `IdentityUser<T>`. `IdentityUser` extends `IdentityUser<string>`. It seems `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` insists on the `IdentityUser`'s `TKey` being a `string`

Comment: @canton7 -  What do I do to permenently solve the problem?

Comment: @canton7 - How do I entirely resolve the error: Error CS0311 ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'ApiAuthorizationDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

Comment: You can't use `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` with a custom `IdentityUser<T>` it seems. I'm not sure what you need to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should define your IdentityUserRole to your IdentityUser
and IdentityRole .
i mean define  ApplicationUserRole for ApplicationUser and role
change your classes to something like :

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long , IdentityUserLogin,
ApplicationUserRole ,IdentityUserClaim>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long,ApplicationUserRole >
    {
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
```